# Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Tags: node.js, express, backend, middleware

I am chaining custom middleware function for my route handler in express but I am getting the above(title) error . Why is that?
Here is my code for middleware:

```
const Joi = require("joi");

function validateCredentials(req, res, next) {
    const schema = {

      email: Joi.string()
        .max(1024)
        .required()
        .regex(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/),
      password: Joi.string()
        .min(6)
        .max(255)
        .required()
    };
  const result = Joi.validate({ email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password }, schema);
  if(!result.error) {
      return next();
  }
}

module.exports.validateCredentials = validateCredentials ;
```

Here is route handler:

```
router.post('/api/signup', validateCredentials, passport.authenticate('local-signup'), (req, res) => {
    const response = {};
    response._id = req.user._id;
    response.email = req.user.local.email;
    res.send(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `next` only when validation passes not when there is an error.

Did you try this?

```
if (!result.error) {
  return next();
} else {
  return next(result.error);
}
```